while installing pygobject using python 3.12 having issue on creating metadata
Collecting pygobject
  Using cached pygobject-3.48.1.tar.gz (714 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [21 lines of output]
      + meson setup C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ri32dnv3\pygobject_d0e84d8f741745e3a9aca329ba65bdb9 C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ri32dnv3\pygobject_d0e84d8f741745e3a9aca329ba65bdb9\.mesonpy-7huf72cb -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md -Dtests=false -Dwheel=true --wrap-mode=nofallback --native-file=C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ri32dnv3\pygobject_d0e84d8f741745e3a9aca329ba65bdb9\.mesonpy-7huf72cb\meson-python-native-file.ini
      The Meson build system
      Version: 1.4.0
      Source dir: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ri32dnv3\pygobject_d0e84d8f741745e3a9aca329ba65bdb9
      Build dir: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ri32dnv3\pygobject_d0e84d8f741745e3a9aca329ba65bdb9\.mesonpy-7huf72cb
      Build type: native build
      Project name: pygobject
      Project version: 3.48.1
      WARNING: Failed to activate VS environment: Could not parse vswhere.exe output
     
      ..\meson.build:1:0: ERROR: Unknown compiler(s): [['icl'], ['cl'], ['cc'], ['gcc'], ['clang'], ['clang-cl'], ['pgcc']]
      The following exception(s) were encountered:
      Running `icl ""` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `cl /?` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `cc --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `gcc --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `clang --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `clang-cl /?` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `pgcc --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
     
      A full log can be found at C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ri32dnv3\pygobject_d0e84d8f741745e3a9aca329ba65bdb9\.mesonpy-7huf72cb\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

I'm using Python 3.12 while downloading pygobject as pip install pygobject facing the above issue.

To build that package from source (which is what pip is trying to do, since there are no wheels for that package published on PyPI), you need to install its system dependencies. That includes at a minimum a C compiler, which is what that error message is telling you. You'll also need to install its other system dependencies, which are described in the docs: https://gnome.pages.gitlab.gnome.org/pygobject/guide/sysdeps.html
